iOS Keyboard Toolbar disappearing when consecutive sheets are presented
When adding a Done button to the keyboard toolbar, the toolbar presents and operates as expected on the first view.
If you present multiple views using .sheet() one on top of the other, with each keyboard using the same toolbar and Done button, when you get to the third view that has been presented, the toolbar disappears.
I have tried adding a FocusState, FocusValue, NavigationStack and NavigationView, I have tried making sure the field state is cleared and contained within every view but nothing seems to work.
Any help on this is highly appreciated.  I have battled this bug through 2 different apps and 2 sequential OS versions.  I personally think its a bug in the OS, but want to make sure that it's not me doing something wrong.
Steps to reproduce:

Run the above code.
Focus the text field on view 1
Check there is a done button on the presented keyboard
Present view 2
Focus the text field on view 2
Check there is a done button on the presented keyboard
Present view 3
Check there is a done button on the presented keyboard, it should be missing.
Do the same for view 4, again it should be missing.

Interestingly, if you remove the navigation stack and toolbar from view one, the toolbar on view 3 works, and 4 is missing still.
Tested on XCode Version 15.4
iPhone 15 pro sim
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var isPresenting: Bool = false
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 32) {
                
                TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                
                Button {
                    isPresenting.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Present View")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .padding(.top, 40)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .toolbar {
                
                toolbarContent
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
                
                SecondView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    var toolbarContent: some ToolbarContent {
        
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            KeyboardAccessoryDone(title: "Done Content")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var isPresenting: Bool = false
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 32) {
                
                TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                
                Button {
                    isPresenting.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Present View")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .padding(.top, 40)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .toolbar {
                
                toolbarContent
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
                
                ThirdView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    var toolbarContent: some ToolbarContent {
        
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
            CancelButton {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            KeyboardAccessoryDone(title: "Done Second")
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var isPresenting: Bool = false
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 32) {
                
                TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                
                Button {
                    isPresenting.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Present View")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .padding(.top, 40)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .toolbar {
                
                toolbarContent
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
                
                FourthView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    var toolbarContent: some ToolbarContent {
        
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
            CancelButton {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            KeyboardAccessoryDone(title: "Done Third")
        }
    }
}

struct FourthView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var isPresenting: Bool = false
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 32) {
                
                TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                
                Button {
                    isPresenting.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Present View")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .padding(.top, 40)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .toolbar {
                
                toolbarContent
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    var toolbarContent: some ToolbarContent {
        
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
            CancelButton {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            KeyboardAccessoryDone(title: "Done Forth")
        }
    }
}

public struct KeyboardAccessoryDone: View {

    // MARK: - Properties
    
    private let title: String
    private let onPress: (() -> ())?
    
    // MARK: - Init
    
    public init(
        title: String,
        onPress: (() -> ())? = nil
    ) {
        self.title = title
        self.onPress = onPress
    }
    
    // MARK: - View
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button(title) {
            
            if let onPress {
                /// If the consumer of this view has chosen to inject a completion closure, then call it.
                onPress()
            } else {
                /// If the consumer of this view has omitted to inject a completion closure, then close the keyboard by calling `endEditing`.
                UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct CancelButton: View {
    
    private var onPress: (() -> Void)
    
    public init(
        onPress: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        self.onPress = onPress
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            onPress()
        } label: {
            Text("Cancel")
        }
        .accessibilityIdentifier("cancelButton")
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

